# Why can't Java parse this image?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to load this image using ImageIO.read() using the 1.7.0u JVM:

http://taste-for-adventure.tablespoon.com/files/2012/02/2012-02-05-poll-hotdog-275w.jpg

Chrome has no trouble with it, but Java throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.intFromBigEndian(ICC_Profile.java:1770)
    at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getNumComponents(ICC_Profile.java:1462)
    at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMSTransform.<init>(LCMSTransform.java:122)
    at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMS.createTransform(LCMS.java:76)
    at java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace.fromRGB(ICC_ColorSpace.java:222)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.setImageData(JPEGImageReader.java:635)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:550)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:295)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:427)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:543)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:986)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:966)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
```

Is Java's image reader known to be fragile?  Is there a more robust Java library for loading images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please try the following, This runs without any problem in java 1.6? Does it give the same exception?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ShowImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Debug Frame");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Image image = null;
        JLabel label = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("c:/scratch/hotdog.jpg"));
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            label.setText("Image loading failed");
        }

        frame.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, what's exactly in your code, and which line throws a NullPointerException but the following works fins in Java 6:

```
String imageUrl = "http://taste-for-adventure.tablespoon.com/files/2012/02/2012-02-05-poll-hotdog-275w.jpg";
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageUrl));
if(bi != null)
    System.out.println("Image Loaded!");
else
    System.out.println("Something's wrong...");
```

Sorry but I cannot test it in Java 7 right now...